# iproute2 Inherit or Copy Table

Tags: iproute

I've setup source policy routing on a Linux "router" using :

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table FOO
ip route add default dev eth0 table FOO
```

Packets forwarded from that subnet reach Internet destinations.

Issue is that table FOO does not inherit locally-connected routes from table main.
I could add locally connected routes manually, but obviously that's fragile and requires more maintenance.

I would like table FOO to inherit all routes of table main, and then instead of "ip route add default ...", I could use an "ip route change default".

The default route of table main must stay in place for other subnets.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your actual settings before this ( `ip -br link; ip -4 -br addr` (or without -br if it fails) `ip -4 route`)?  It would help understanding what you're trying to solve. I got it that you want to avoid having to copy almost all routes from main to FOO. I think I have an idea that would be interesting but I'd like to check if it "works" first

Answer (score 3):

Here is the usual way new routing tables and rules are added, which the OP doesn't want:

1. create a new routing table that includes "exceptions", called `FOO`
2. add a rule with a condition that selects this table `FOO`
3. because the rule gets a lower (better) priority the new table `FOO` is read first, thus usually entirely bypassing the `main` table. To "correct" this problem, routes from the `main` table are copied to table `FOO`.

Rules would look like this:

```
# ip rule 
0:  from all lookup local 
32765:  from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup FOO 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

OP doesn't wish to have to do 3., because it increases administration burden when routes are changed.

From what I understand this is what OP is wishing:

1. every local traffic should be handled with the usual routes from table `main`
2. if the traffic is coming from `192.168.1.0/24` its default route should be taken from table `FOO` (here `dev eth0`)
3. else, the traffic will use the "usual" default route.

Let's implement it in this order instead of the usual order. The result might not be exactly what was described in the question, but should be what was wished. Without the actual problem to solve and the proper configuration given from OP, some things might seem awkward (like reusing the output of `ip route` to move the default route from table `main` to table `default`).

Starting from usual rules:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Note that the `default` table is empty (by default) and free to use.

```
# ip route show table default
#
```

1. move the rule looking up `main` to a lower priority

   ```
   # ip rule add priority 32000 from all lookup main
   # ip rule del priority 32766
   ```
2. implement exceptions

   ```
   # ip route add default dev eth0 table FOO
   # ip rule add priority 32100 from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup FOO
   ```
3. move the "usual" default route from table `main` to table `default`, to allow exceptions to trigger at rule 32100. Rule 32767 will still be giving the default route from the `default` table if no match was found before, there's no connectivity loss.

   ```
   # ip route add $(ip route show 0.0.0.0/0) table default
   # ip route del default
   ```

Rules will now look like this:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32000:  from all lookup main 
32100:  from 192.168.1.0/24 lookup FOO 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

A few examples in a container (that won't make much sense, that's just to see the tables involved):

```
# ip -br link
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
eth0@if12        UP             66:d4:11:94:49:5f <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
local0@if9       UP             00:16:3e:6a:c1:e9 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
# ip -4 -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 
local0@if9       UP             10.0.3.66/24 
# ip route
10.0.3.0/24 dev local0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.3.66 
# ip route show table FOO
default dev eth0 scope link 
# ip route show table default
default via 10.0.3.1 dev local0 

# ip -o route get 10.0.3.2
10.0.3.2 dev local0 src 10.0.3.66 \    cache 
# ip -o route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 10.0.3.1 dev local0 table default src 10.0.3.66 \    cache 
# ip -o route get 8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 iif local0
8.8.8.8 from 192.168.1.2 dev eth0 table FOO \    cache  iif local0
```

That's it. The only usage difference is that the "usual" default route has now to be set in table `default` (`253`) instead of table `main` (`254`). Boot scripts have to be adapted to handle it: settings should not state a default route or gateway but should run an additional custom script which will do `ip route add default ... table default`. For Debian this can be done with `post-up` commands (*eg* `post-up ip route add default via xxx table default || :`) in `/etc/network/interfaces`. For RHEL7 this should be done with [route-XXX](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-editing_network_configuration_files#sec-networkscripts-static-routes-ip-command) files. For systemd's new network methods, I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

Just add

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table main suppress_prefixlength 0
```

Packets will go to `table main` and find a route, but the default route in `table main` won't be used.

Then packets go to `table FOO` and got routed to `eth0`.